# Communication between web applications in a weblogic cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic11g

I have a problem and I am wondering what the best way of solving it is.

Basically I have two web apps in a clustered environment (weblogic 11g).

The first web application is for uploading "documents" and managing these web applications as viewable (or not) in the second web app. The documents are stored in a database which both web applications can read

The second web application can be thought of as a document viewer.

Because loading these documents can be very slow. I'd like to load them as soon as I can rather waiting for a request.

A pull model where the web application periodically checks the database for new/removed/updated documents doesn't seem to be very practical.

What would be the best way of signalling when an user (admin) of the first webapp has updated a document, so that the second webapp can retrieve the document from the database?

My first thoughts were to use a JMS Server, but that seems a little heavy for such a simple signalling system.

What would be the best fit for this scenario?

- A JMS Server for the cluster?
- A JNDI Object?

Answer (score 0):

Why is JMS heavy? You already use an application server with integrated JMS.

- You could use one queue dedicated to each cluster node.
- On upload you could post one message in each queue
- On each cluster node there is a job which acts as `QueueReceiver` which in turn updates it's local cache

As an alternative you could try to have a servlet/web service which is called for each cluster node (which again updates the local cache).